# Multiple News Sources from News API

Tags: java, android

I'm currently building a news application for Android.
I'm using News API for the data sources I have it running well but with only one news source is there anyway you can add multiple news sources?

Here is my java Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String API_KEY = "8190df9eb51445228e397e4185311a66";
    String NEWS_SOURCE = "bbc-news";
    ListView listNews;
    ProgressBar loader;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    static final String KEY_URLTOIMAGE = "urlToImage";
    static final String KEY_PUBLISHEDAT = "publishedAt";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNews);
        loader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);
        listNews.setEmptyView(loader);



        if(Function.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
        {
            DownloadNews newsTask = new DownloadNews();
            newsTask.execute();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    class DownloadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String xml = "";

            String urlParameters = "";
            xml = Function.excuteGet("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source="+NEWS_SOURCE+"&sortBy=top&apiKey="+API_KEY, urlParameters);
            return  xml;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {

                if(xml.length()>10){ // Just checking if not empty

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(xml);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("articles");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, jsonObject.optString(KEY_AUTHOR).toString());
                            map.put(KEY_TITLE, jsonObject.optString(KEY_TITLE).toString());
                            map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, jsonObject.optString(KEY_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                            map.put(KEY_URL, jsonObject.optString(KEY_URL).toString());
                            map.put(KEY_URLTOIMAGE, jsonObject.optString(KEY_URLTOIMAGE).toString());
                            map.put(KEY_PUBLISHEDAT, jsonObject.optString(KEY_PUBLISHEDAT).toString());
                            dataList.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    ListNewsAdapter adapter = new ListNewsAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataList);
                    listNews.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listNews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("url", dataList.get(+position).get(KEY_URL));
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }



    }
```

I tried looking at the documentation on their website https://newsapi.org/ 
and couldn't see anything I needed in fairness this is probably the most complicated task i've tried to date any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm sure i've overlooked things but the vast majority of this has all been new to me

Comment: Probably, you have to ask the guys at News API if you want to use their API and it does not provide a function you are looking for

Comment: Don't put all the code in one Activity/Fragment. Follow [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle while designing your program. It will help you to see your code by functional blocks and to understand where you can reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

The updated documentation for the v2 News API can be found on their [website](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything).
The request parameter 'source' is now 'sources'. To answer the main question about adding multiple news sources, you can create a String of multiple news sources, maximum of 20, separated by commas.

```
String NEWS_SOURCE = "bbc-news,bloomberg,business-insider-uk";
```

the modified string including parameters for the api request:

```
"https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?source="+NEWS_SOURCE+"&apiKey="+API_KEY
```

note: If you still want to utilize the 'sortBy' parameter, top is no longer valid, options are now: relevancy, popularity, and publishedAt